# how to compare unicode characters in objective-c?

Tags: ios

am trying to compare unicode character in my app ,,

when i use

```
if([str charcterAtIndex:i] == 'w')
  nslog......
```

it works correctly

but it doesn't when the letter is an Arabic letter as 'ب' !!!

is there a specific way to do so..

thnx

Comment: I wanted to use it for encoding ...but NSUTF16StringEncoding solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make them UTF-8

```
const char* utfStr1 = [yourString UTF8String];
const char* utfStr2 = [yourString2 UTF8String];
```

and then compare them

```
if([utfStr1 isEqualToString:utfStr2]) NSLog(@"true");
```

Comment: What? isEqualToString: is a NSString method no? This does not work.